# Understanding expansion in \addtocontents

Tags: expl3, expansion, auxiliary-files, write

I am confused about how expansion works in `\addtocontents`, or more precisely in `\protected@write`. As I understand it, `\addtocontents` should essentially expand its second argument with `\protected@edef` and write the result to the aux file. With this understanding, I would expect the behavior to be (up to a `\protected@`) the same as

```
\iow_shipout:Ne \@auxout
  {
    \exp_not:N \@writefile { #1 } { #2 }
  }
```

But as the following MWE shows, they behave differently when trying to prevent expansion inside their argument with `\exp_not:n`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \naiveaddtocontents } { m m }
  {
    \iow_shipout:Ne \@auxout
      {
        \exp_not:N \@writefile { #1 } { #2 }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\abc{some text}

\begin{document}

bla

\ExplSyntaxOn

% this does what I expect
\protected@edef \l_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:n { \abc } }
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

% so does this
\naiveaddtocontents{ lof }{ \exp_not:n { \abc } }

% this does not
\addtocontents{ lof }{ \exp_not:n { \abc } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The aux file looks like

```
\relax 
\@writefile {lof}{\abc }
\@writefile{lof}{some text}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

So `\naiveaddtocontents` is preventing expansion with `\exp_not:n`, but `\addtocontents` is not. For my use case where I don't want the argument expanded at all, I can just use this `\naiveaddtocontents`. But why doesn't `\exp_not:n` work as I incorrectly expected in `\addtocontents`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\addtocontents` uses `\protected@write`. Below is the definition of `\protected@write` from `source2e`:

```
\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
```

The relevant part is `\edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%`. If the above definition of `\protected@write` would be added in the document and in the previous line, `\edef` is replaced by `\def` then `\addtocontents{ lof }{ \exp_not:n { \abc } }` gives `\@writefile{lof}{\abc }` in the .aux file.

However with `\edef`, an additional expansion occurs such that `\addtocontents{ lof }{ \exp_not:n { \abc } }` gives `\@writefile{lof}{some text}` in the .aux file.

Therefore with `\edef`, the example works if an additional `\exp_not:n` is added: `\addtocontents{ lof }{ \exp_not:n { \exp_not:n { \abc } } }` gives `\@writefile{lof}{\abc }` in the .aux file.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give more specifics? I am interested in the why, not just a fix

Comment: @mbert See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, you're saying that the `\edef` strips one `\exp_not:n`, and since `\write` expands its argument another expansion takes place when `\reserved@a` is executed, hence the need for two `\exp_not:n`'s?

Comment: @mbert Your clarification is indeed what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the definition of `\addtocontents`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 14289:
\long\def\addtocontents#1#2{%
  \protected@write\@auxout
      {\let\label\@gobble \let\index\@gobble \let\glossary\@gobble}%
      {\string\@writefile{#1}{#2}}}
```

With your naive definition you'd have big problems if you have a `\label` in the second argument to `\addtocontents`. But let's leave this out, because it's a technicality.

Suppose you want `\addtocontents{toc}{Hey, this is \textbf{boldface}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \naiveaddtocontents } { m m }
  {
    \iow_shipout:Ne \@auxout
      {
        \exp_not:N \@writefile { #1 } { #2 }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text

\addtocontents{toc}{Hey, this is \textbf{boldface}}

\naiveaddtocontents{toc}{Hey, this is \textbf{boldface}}

\end{document}
```

The console will print

```
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 21 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifmmode on line 21 was incomplete)</usr/local/texlive/2023
/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
```

and the `aux` file will have

```
\relax
\@writefile{toc}{Hey, this is \textbf  {boldface}}
\@writefile {toc}{Hey, this is \protect \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \edef l3backend-pdftex.def{boldface}\let \futurelet \@let@token \let \protect \relax \edef cmr{cmr}\edef cmss{cmss}\edef cmtt{cmtt}\def ##1,b,{}\series@check@toks {,ulm,elm,lm,slm,mm,sbm,bm,ebm,ubm,muc,mec,mc,msc,msx,mx,mex,mux,{}{},b,}\edef {}\edef b{b}\def ##1,m,{}\series@check@toks {,ulm,elm,lm,slm,mm,sbm,bm,ebm,ubm,muc,mec,mc,msc,msx,mx,mex,mux,{}{},m,}\edef {}\edef m{m}\protect \let }
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Not really what you want to see, do you? Let's fix it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \naiveaddtocontents } { m m }
  {
    \iow_shipout:Ne \@auxout
      {
        \exp_not:N \@writefile { #1 } { \text_expand:n { #2 } }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\newcommand{\abc}{some text}

\begin{document}

Some text

\addtocontents{toc}{Hey, this is \textbf{boldface} and \abc}

\naiveaddtocontents{toc}{Hey, this is \textbf{boldface} and \abc}

\end{document}
```

Now the `aux` file will have

```
\relax
\@writefile{toc}{Hey, this is \textbf  {boldface} and some text}
\@writefile {toc}{Hey, this is \textbf {boldface} and some text}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Basically, `\text_expand:n` will do roughly the same as `\protected@edef` does, but leaving the resulting token list wrapped in `\unexpanded`.

If you do `\exp_not:n` (that is, `\unexpanded`), TeX will do *no* expansion, so you get `\abc` and not its expansion.

Without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \naiveaddtocontents } { m m }
  {
    \iow_shipout:ce { @auxout }
      {
        \token_to_str:c { @writefile } { #1 } { \text_expand:n { #2 } }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Instead of `\token_to_str:c` you can use `\exp_not:c`